# Is there a better way than meta refresh when connection is lost?

Tags: javascript, php

I use often `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">` to update my page.

I noticed that this stops, if for any reason the connection to the server get lost for a while.

My first thought was to add a PHP information, when the page will be updated the next time, and a JavaScript variable what time it is now. This would require an action from the user. Can I do that differently?

Comment: You can call `location.reload()`.  Or you can use AJAX or Web Sockets.

Comment: do you need to refresh the whole page? or just part of it?

Comment: I need to reload the entire page

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout`

```
window.addEventListener('load', reloadPage, false);

function reloadPage() {
    // reload the page in 60 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 60000);
}
```